# How to remove directory with error input i/o devive on hard disk

Tags: io

I have a hard disk with an error i/o.

This is caused in a folder which I needed to delete in order to restore things.

But deleting the folder gives the error. How can I force to delete this folder?

I cannot run chkdsk as it will take 8 hours. I need to delete it now.

Windows64b

Comment: This is not possible. You cannot delete anything from the area of the disk that is "damaged" without "fixing" it first.

Comment: ... if it can be fixed at all... :)

Comment: How would removing the folder allow you to recover the data?  If the disk has I/O errors the disk needs to be replaced, if you are getting I/O and you have no backups, it likely is far to late for the data.

Answer (score 1):

Your filesystem seems to be damaged. Trying to force-delete a damaged folder will probably result in even more damage (somewhere between minor file loss and computer not booting at all). Run `chkdsk` and let it do its job, then delete the folder.

When you have hard disk-related problems, don't hurry. It will only make things worse.